# How to paint part of DateListPlot?

Tags: color, date-and-time

My graph is about fires (burned area) over 12 years presented in one Date List Log Plot. Because most of fires are in summer (as expected) I would like to highlight that with different background colors. 
How can I paint seasons in Date List Plot in different colors? I want to put different background color for winter, spring... Thank you!

Comment: You can put a coloured Rectangle in the Prolog option.

Comment: @Szabolcs I was writing a comment in your answer. It took me too long (more than one hour!) because I was interrupted many times by stupid things like work. Now I wonder if non-posted comments to deleted answers are second class citizens of this universe or are just kept in a wormhole until the Schröedinger's cat takes a nap.

Comment: @belisarius I'm sorry, I didn't know.  Do you need me to undelete it?  Verbeia's answer was a bit more detailed then mine and I didn't want to keep both ...

Comment: @Szabolcs Nahhh .. Let's the wormhole got filled up.

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest using `Prolog` and graphics rectangles like this

```
fakedata = 
  Transpose[{DatePlus[{1977, 1}, {#, "Month"}] & /@ 
     Range[0, 33*12 - 2], 
    FoldList[#1 + #2 &, 59.5, 
     RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0.002, 0.5], 33*12 - 2]]}];
```

You don't need `AbsoluteTime` to define the dimensions of the rectangles, but you do need to define the vertical range of the rectangles to be beyond the range of your data. You can't use `Scaled` in just one dimension. The code below shows how to have multiple rectangles, though in this case I have used recessions and milder economic downturns in Australia rather than summers as the dates for the rectangles. (I happened to have a similar graph lying around.) If you want different colors for the different rectangles, just intersperse the colors in between the `Rectangle` objects in the list.

```
DateListPlot[fakedata, Joined -> True, 
 Prolog -> {GrayLevel[0.8], 
   Rectangle[{{1981, 6}, 0}, {{1983, 7}, 90}], 
  Rectangle[{{1989, 11}, 0}, {{1992, 3}, 90}], 
   Rectangle[{{2008, 1}, 0}, {{2009, 7}, 90}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved me!

Comment: @Danijel, if this answered your question, you might consider accepting the answer ;).

Answer (score 5):

Here is the version I use (it is quite similar to Verbeia's, but I don't want to compute the vertical range every time):

```
ClearAll[dateListPlotShaded];
Options[dateListPlotShaded] = 
  Join[DeleteCases[Options[DateListPlot], GridLines -> _], 
        {GridLines -> None, ShadeColor -> LightBlue, ShadeOpacity -> 1}];

With[{opt = First /@ Options[DateListPlot]},
  dateListPlotShaded[ddata_, ShadeDates_, OptionsPattern[]] :=
     Module[{yRange, yPadding},
        With[{plot=DateListPlot[ddata, Sequence@@((#->OptionValue[#])& /@ opt)]},
           yRange= Last[PlotRange/.AbsoluteOptions[plot, PlotRange]];
           yPadding = If[OptionValue[Frame] === True, - .2 Subtract@@yRange, 0];                                
           Show[plot,
             Prolog -> {{OptionValue[ShadeColor], 
               Opacity[OptionValue[ShadeOpacity]], 
                 (Rectangle[
                    {AbsoluteTime[#[[1]]], 
                       yRange[[1]] - yPadding}, 
                    {AbsoluteTime[#[[2]]], 
                       yRange[[2]] + yPadding}
                    ]&) /@ ShadeDates}, 
             {OptionValue[Prolog]}}]]]];
```

Plotting the data:

```
fakedata = 
  Transpose[{DatePlus[{1977, 1}, {#, "Month"}] & /@ 
    Range[0, 33*12 - 2], 
    FoldList[#1 + #2 &, 59.5, 
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0.002, 0.5], 33*12 - 2]]}];

dateListPlotShaded[fakedata, {{{1981, 6}, {1983, 7}}, {{1989, 11}, {1992, 3}}, 
   {{2008, 1}, {2009, 7}}}, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

You can use `dateListPlotShaded` with all the options of `DateListPlot` (including `Prolog` and with `Frame -> False`).

Comment: Little bit to much for my poor knowledge of programming but I will bookmark this for one day when I will be better and smarter! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Here's another suggestion - 
there are (at least) two caveats:

1. you need rather dense data (I fill points from axis, so not really good for only single points in a year)
2. I can't get it working for `DateListPlot`

Nevertheless, it looks quite ok to do that sort of coloring for e.g. financial data. And maybe it helps you with your fires.

So in that sense, we can load:

```
data = FinancialData["IBM", "Jan. 1, 2004"];
```

And then, we define colors per month (group of months):

```
setup = {{{11, 12, 1}, ColorData["SolarColors"][1/3]}, 
{{2, 3, 4}, ColorData["SolarColors"][2/3]}, 
{{5, 6, 7}, ColorData["SolarColors"][3/3]}, 
{{8, 9, 10}, ColorData["SolarColors"][0/3]}};
```

Then:

```
DateListPlot[data, Joined -> True, 
    ColorFunction -> ((Which[MemberQ[setup[[1, 1]], #], setup[[1, 2]], 
    MemberQ[setup[[2, 1]], #], setup[[2, 2]], 
    MemberQ[setup[[3, 1]], #], setup[[3, 2]], 
    MemberQ[setup[[4, 1]], #], setup[[4, 2]]] &)@
    ToExpression@DateString[#1, "Month"] &), Filling -> Axis, 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ImageSize -> Large]
```

and get:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is also helpfull fo rsome of my graphs!

Comment: @danijel: you are welcome!